# When is Qgis 1.9 being released

Tags: qgis

I've been working in the alpha of 1.9 for quite a while (because of doing bug reports) and I like it a lot. It's more than a year since 1.8 was released, so I wonder when 1.9 is expected out.

Comment: I thought I read that they are bypassing 1.9 and moving on to 2.0, can anyone else confirm that?

Comment: Yes that is true. 1.9 is the dev name for 2.0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to an event which is too localized in time.

Answer (score 11):

QGIS 2.0 (1.9 is the dev name) will be out when it's out. We don't have an offical release date as we are working on squashing some of the blocking bugs.  Once these are done I suspect release will follow closely.

The main aim at the moment is a release before/on FOSS4G in September.